# Display Two Fragments at the same time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

From `FragmentPagerAdapter` in `case 0` I instantiated  `fragment A` this fragment I wanted to display display two fragments inside `frag A`. The view is not displaying. MyFragmentPagerAdapter is called by the main class to populate the viewpager.

```
 MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
final int MARGIN = 16;
leftFrag = new RoundedColourFragment(con.getResources().getColor(
        R.color.android_green), 1f, MARGIN, MARGIN / 2, MARGIN, MARGIN);
rightFrag = new RoundedColourFragment(con.getResources().getColor(
        R.color.honeycombish_blue), 2f, MARGIN / 2, MARGIN, MARGIN,
        MARGIN);

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragg, leftFrag, "left");
ft.add(R.id.fragg2, rightFrag, "right");
ft.commit();

return rootView;
} 
}
```

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <FrameLayout 

            android:id="@+id/fragg"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

      <FrameLayout

            android:id="@+id/fragg2"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to nest fragments inside of fragments, you have to use `getChildFragmentManager()` to set up the nested fragments, not `getFragmentManager()`. `getChildFragmentManager()` is part of API Level 17, and it is also in the Android Support package's backport of fragments.