# How to display two fragments at the same time using TabLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I use  [Android Tab Example](https://github.com/InnovateCode/Android-Tab-Example)  with two tabs, view pager and fragments (structure on the image):[image]
For get fragments i use [the solution from this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035090/how-to-get-existing-fragments-when-using-fragmentpageradapter)
*When my device is rotation i want to display two fragments at the same time.*
 I the [stackoverflow.com/questions/17970021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970021) a similar problem, but I don't know how to apply the solution to my task, **because i have TabLayout**.
If you know idea, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

In activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
   </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

In MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        replaceFragment(0);

  }

       public void replaceFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                fragment = new TabOneFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new TabTwoFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (null != fragment) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    }

}
```

in TabOneFragment.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class TabOneFragment extends Fragment {
    private View inflatedView = null;

    public TabOneFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_one, container, false);

      return this.inflatedView;
  }
}
```

in TabTwoFragment.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class TabTwoFragment extends Fragment {
    private View inflatedView = null;

    public TabTwoFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_two, container, false);

      return this.inflatedView;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but i don't want replace fragment. I want displayTWO fragment together.

Comment: You can display them together by creating two framelayout in activity_main.xml 
and in MainActivity.java  
Fragment fragment1,fragment2; 
fragment1 = new TabOneFragment()
fragment2 = new TabTwoFragment();            
FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content1, fragment1);
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content2, fragment2);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

Comment: You mean, that i need create activity_main.xml with two framelayout for change device orientation?

Comment: Yes, create two framelayout in portrait or orientation
For example
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
    >
   </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
       
    >
   </FrameLayout>

Comment: Yes. And you mean that i don't need use tab layout and pager view?

Comment: Yes, but that is depending on  app design.